# logback dosen't work in Weblogic12c

Tags: logback, openjpa, weblogic12c

My Java EE 6 application uses slf4j with logback as logging framework. I have openjpa  custom logging which is not working on Weblogic while it was ok on glassfish before (whit openjpa 1.2).
When I add my custom log factory to "openjpa.log" property in persistence.xml, weblogic ignores this and doesn't work.

my custom log factory:

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="com.kishware.core.log.openjpa.CustomSLF4JLogFactory"/>
```

Here is the weblogic console output when ignores the property:

```
<Aug 17, 2013 11:29:35 AM GMT+04:30> <Warning> <J2EE> <BEA-160202> <You have specified a openjpa.Log setting in your configuration for persistence unit banco-product#pu-channel-manager. This setting will be ignored and all log messages will be sent to the WebLogic Server logging subsystem. Trace-level logging is controlled by the various JPA-specific debug settings in config.xml, or through the WebLogic Server Administration Console.>
```

I should mention that I'm using JPA 2.1 with Toplink implementation.
I would be happy to get some hints, how this could be solved.

Answer (score 1):

> I should mention that I'm using JPA 2.1 with Toplink implementation

Right there is your problem. You're trying to configure Toplink (and I think you mean EclipseLink) with OpenJPA configuration properties.